# MySQL Transactions using C++?

Tags: c++, mysql, transactions

How would I go about wrapping an amount of queries in a transaction in C++? I'm working on Ubuntu 10, using this file:

`#include "/usr/include/mysql/mysql.h"`

with C++ to interact with a MySQL database.

EDIT: Right now I'm running queries through a small wrapper class, like so:

```
MYSQL_RES* PDB::query(string query)
{
  int s = mysql_query(this->connection, query.c_str());

  if( s != 0 )
    {
      cout << mysql_error(&this->mysql) << endl;
    }

  return mysql_store_result(this->connection);
}

MYSQL_ROW PDB::getarray(MYSQL_RES *res)
{
  return mysql_fetch_row( res );
}

// example one
MYSQL_RES res = db->query( "SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE 1" );
while( MYSQL_ROW row = db->getarray( res ) )
  {
    cout << row[0] << endl;
  }
```

Comment: I think you should reconsider the selected answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could always just run `START TRANSACTION` / `COMMIT` / ... manually.

Another way would be to create a wrapper class which runs START TRANSACTION in the constructor, provides commit/rollback functions and, depending on your use case, does a rollback upon destruction.

Comment: SO I can just make one big query string like: "START TRANSACTION; UPDATE ...; UPDATE ...; UPDATE ...; COMMIT;" Then run that through the regular mysql_query() ?

Comment: You don't necessarily have to put everything in one statement. 

db->query("START TRANSACTION"); -- 
db->query("UPDATE ..."); -- 
db->query("UPDATE ..."); -- 
db->query("COMMIT");  ...

Answer (score 7):

If you use [MySQL++](http://tangentsoft.net/mysqlpp/), you get [RAII](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/RAII) transaction behavior with [Transaction objects](http://tangentsoft.net/mysqlpp/doc/html/userman/tutorial.html#Transaction):

```
mysqlpp::Connection con( /* login parameters here */ );
auto query = con.query("UPDATE foo SET bar='qux' WHERE ...");
mysqlpp::Transaction trans(con);
if (auto res = query.execute()) {
    // query succeeded; optionally use res
    trans.commit();  // commit DB changes
}
// else, commit() not called, so changes roll back when
// 'trans' goes out of scope, possibly by stack unwinding
// due to a thrown exception.
```